# Python - DNS lookup from SQL database

Tags: python, sql-server, dns

I was hoping you could point me in the right direction about a little problem I'm having.

I want to create a basic web app that performs DNS queries to validate whether a specific set of DNS records are active or not. The DNS records are all A records and are hosted on an SQL-based CMDB.

I'm a fan of python and would prefer to use it but I have no idea where to start. The use case I'm looking at is as follows:

> - Browse to http://hostname/pythonDnsTool.html
> - Click [RUN QUERY] button
> - Script queries the **[DnsARecord]** table to validate whether a list of dnsNames exist or not
> - Upon completion http://hostname/pythonDnsTool.html returns a list of queried domains with a YES or NO

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Westie5017

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tools, which one is the best depends on your needs.

**1]** A great python tool that does what you ask and a lot more is **scapy**. 
For example:

```
>>> packet = DNSQR()
>>> packet.show()
###[ DNS Question Record ]###
  qname= '.'
  qtype= A
  qclass= IN
```

As you can see it gives you the ability to craft your packets in high level.
For example if you wanted to send a simple DNS query and get an answer back you could do something like that:

```
sr1(IP(dst="some_ip")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="")))
```

But again this is only a minimal example of the things you can do. 
For more information take a look at:
[here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) and [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) (scapy's general documentation)

and specifically for **DNS** take a look at [here](https://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-p-09-scapy-and-dns/) where you can find a lot of examples.

**2]** Alternatively you can use the built-in `socket` module:

```
import socket
info = socket.getaddrinfo('a_domain', a_port)
socket.gethostbyname('a_domain') # but this will give only the ip
```

**3]** Finally you can use [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html).